# Access file sharing

Tags: database, ms-access, cloud, file-sharing

I have a nicely designed access database, complete with layed out forms and macros behind many buttons that filter through search boxes and do many other functions.

My problem is that I am sending this database to multiple people who want to add new records, however when they give me back their edited database (now with new records", i cant import them, because another person who has also handed me their edited version of the database needs their records added and access doesnt allow me to import these records because unique ID's have been created by both people and clash when i try to import them both in.

I have tried some websites that claim to import my database and allow cloud editing, however i lose all the functionality and layout of my forms / macros as the websites dont support it.

What would be the best solution so that i can get multiple people adding new records at the same time? Are there any websites that offer this? Or is there a way inside access to reassign the Unique ID's if they are already in the system?

Answer (score 0):

Split the database into frontend and backend parts. Backend sits on server and frontend links to backend. Each user runs their own copy of frontend. However, if your users do not have access to same network, you are in a pickle. Have you looked into Sharepoint and Azure?

I have designed a db for users that did not have connection to our network. These were construction site field offices. The main office had the master database. Field offices were given an Access file where they entered records during life of the project and at the end they sent in the file and code in the master imported records. Since all data was new there was no concern for conflicting updates. Simplest way I found to accomplish was to not use Autonumber primary key.

I do have another db that required merging data from multiple Access files and those files did use Autonumber primary key. The import code was more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the field size of your AutoNumber ID fields to `Replication ID` instead of `Long Integer`. It is extremely unlikely that two users will create records with the same ID.

Comment: It is set to an autonumber and will asign ID's accordingly, this doest help for when two people create the same ID on different files of the database

Comment: If you set the Field Size (not Field Type) of your AutoNumber field to `Replication ID` it will assign the ID values like `{165742E8-4FFA-4969-B9EB-9DEF093415C6}` instead of integers starting at `1`. These `Replication ID` values are unlikely to be duplicated by other users in other files.